Lebesgue-measurability of projective sets in ZFC
On the Lebesgue-measurability of the projective subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, the 4th page (pg. 570) of this article by Woodin says:

Theorem (Godel). Assume ZFC is consistent. Then so is ZFC + “There is a nonmeasurable projective set”.

So far so good, I think I understand this. What I don’t get is on the next page:

The consistency with ZFC that every projective set is Lebesgue measurable, while true, cannot be proved assuming just the consistency of ZFC.

How can it be “true” but not provable? Or maybe more correctly: in what sense is it provable?

I’ve read about additional axioms that imply the measurability of all projective sets, but that just begs the question as to whether $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + “extra axiom(s)” is consistent (assuming $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is consistent).


Provable assuming the consistency of ZFC + a suitable large cardinal hypothesis.

Woodin is arguing for a richer theory than ZFC alone. From the bottom of page 2 of the linked paper:

The empirical completeness of arithmetic coupled with an obvious failure of completeness for set theory has led some to speculate that the phenomenon of independence is fundamental, in particular that the continuum problem is inherently vague with no solution [... but I will challenge this.] I shall begin by describing some classical questions of Second Order Number Theory — this is the theory of the integers together with all sets of integers — which are also not solvable from ZFC. Here I maintain there is a
solution: there are axioms for Second Order Number Theory which provide a theory as canonical as that of number theory. These relatively new axioms provide insights [in]to Second Order Number Theory which transcend those provided by even ZFC.

So this is how his remark should be understood:

The consistency with ZFC that every projective set is Lebesgue measurable, while a consequence of [certain canonical axioms], cannot be proved assuming just the consistency of ZFC." (Altered part bolded.)

Specifically, the additional axiom in question (in this case at least) is Projective Determinacy. See the summary at the bottom of page 575.
Of course this is less "punchy." For what it's worth, while I do like many things about his expository writing, I personally don't like how Woodin uses the word "true" in that context, at least partly because I don't share all (many?) of the philosophical assumptions behind his use of the word.

Do you happen to have an idea of what “richer theory than ZFC alone” he has in mind? In the passage you quoted, he makes a passing reference (without further details) to “relatively new axioms” for second-order number theory, and towards the end he seems to argue emphatically for Projective Determinacy as an additional axiom to ZFC. But it’s not totally clear to me exactly what theory he’s taking to be “the truth” which implies that measurability of projective sets is “true”.

@NikS It's just ZFC + Projective Determinacy. (See the bottom of page 575.) Philosophical details aside (which again I find uncompelling at least), it is indeed true that PD implies all projective sets are measurable (see Truss, Lebesgue measure and games).

Is the theory ZFC + Projective Determinacy equiconsistent with ZFC?

@MikhailKatz No - PD has significant large cardinal strength. See the bottom of page 573 (+ the top of the next page) of Woodin's article.

If so, then your claim that certain canonical axioms enable one to prove the Lebesgue measurability of every projective set in a way that's "consistent with ZFC", is misleading.

@MikhailKatz It's not my claim. I'm paraphrasing Woodin.

Well Woodin made a platonist statement, whereas you proposed a non-platonist paraphrase of what Woodin wrote, in terms of equiconsistency.  Isn't your paraphrase inaccurate in its own right?  Woodin did not say anything about equiconsistency (only about "truth").

Woodin's remark may be tongue-in-cheek.  Note that given enough Woodin cardinals, all projective sets are Lebesgue measurable.  As he has written elsewhere, assuming the absence of Woodin cardinals is "obviously false".
